Problema al reemplazar datos en csv
Me encuentro practicando Python con Pandas. Tengo un archivo .csv que he creado para poder practicar, me encuentro utilizando .replace para poder reemplazar el nombre de "Bastian" a "Arturo" pero al momento de ejecutar el script no sucede nada.
Archivo .csv:
'Bastian', 'Perez', 24
'Rocio', 'Montecinos', 20
'Eva', 'Fernandez', 65
'Joel', 'Cardenas', 74

Código de Python:

# Leyendo y agregando el nombre de los encabezados para el archivo.
df = pd.read_csv("resolviendo_problemas/datos.csv",
                 names=["nombre", "apellido", "edad"])

df['nombre'].replace("Bastian", "Arturo", inplace=True)
print(df['nombre'])


No reemplaza nada porque la la cadena Bastian no existe en esa columna, es 'Bastian', los nombres y apellidos en tu csv están acotados por comillas simples. Por lo tanto, puedes hacer:
df['nombre'].replace("'Bastian'", "'Arturo'", inplace=True)

que no es lo deseado generalmente, ya que las comillas generalmente se usan para acotar/delimitar lo que debe ser considerado un solo dato, pero no son parte del campo en si. Lo apropiado sería usar el argumento quotechar proporcionado el carácter que se está usando para acotar:
df = pd.read_csv(
    "resolviendo_problemas/datos.csv",
    quotechar="'",
    names=["nombre", "apellido", "edad"]
)
df['nombre'].replace("Bastian", "Arturo", inplace=True)

Dado que el csv lo has creado tu a modo de ejemplo, considera simplemente cambiar las comillas simples a dobles. El "estándar" (ver RFC 4180 y RFC 7111, aunque el formato csv no está realmente estandarizado) es usar comillas dobles en vez de simples para acotar los items, que es de hecho el valor por defecto del argumento quotechar.
En este ejemplo, realmente puedes prescindir totalmente de usar acotado si quieres, una de las principales razones de agregarlo es poder usar el propio separador dentro del item sin que sea interpretado como tal, por ejemplo:
Nombre,edad
"Alonso Quijano, el Bueno",50

otro caso típico es el de la coma como separador decimal a la vez que se usa como delimitador del csv.

Muchas gracias, no tenía la menor idea que se fijaba en eso, es recomendable entonces crear el csv con ¿doble comillas?, o como sería el "standard". Después trabajaré con csv más grandes que quizás me descargue por ahí, pero este lo cree yo.

Realmente no hay un estándar como tal para csv, lo más cercano es rfc4180. Si vas a entrecomillar los campos, lo "estándar" es usar comillas dobles, de hecho es el valor por defecto de quotechar.

@BastianMatteo no se el tamaño de tus csvs, pero si hablamos de "gigabytes", ten en cuenta que pandas carga todo el csv en memoria

@DanteS. te refieres a que sería como una mala práctica ¿el cargar todo el csv?. Me encuentro recién aprendiendo esto para luego intentar seguir un roadmap de analista de datos o para Machine Learning. Gracias Dante quedo atento.
